# Program crashes for an API call iPhone

Tags: ios, json

I have two pages:

Login page and sign up page:

For login page, I am using the following to get the information and pass the fail or success response to user:

```
- (void)login:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.appDel.api loginWithEmail:self.email.text
                           password:self.password.text
                  completionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error) {
                      if (error) {
                          NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
                      } else {
                          if ([[response objectForKey:Status] isEqualToString:Success]) {
                              self.currentUser = [response objectForKey:kResponseUser];
                              self.currentUserProfile = [response objectForKey:Profile];
                              [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"FAIL: %@", response);
                              [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed"
                                                          message:[response description]
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                          }
                      }
                  }];
}
```

Using this for login page, if user don't complete the two required texfields or have one of them filled the other empty and press Login he will receive fail message.

in the sign up case however the program crashes when textfields are empty and we click on sign up:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
> *** First throw call stack: (0x15d2012 0x12dfe7e 0x1598a95 0x15c54e9 0xe116 0x7955 0x12f3705 0x22a920 0x22a8b8 0x2eb671 0x2ebbcf 0x2ead38 0x25a33f 0x25a552 0x2383aa 0x229cf8 0x2634df9 0x2634ad0 0x1547bf5 0x1547962 0x1578bb6 0x1577f44 0x1577e1b 0x26337e3 0x2633668 0x22765c 0x297d 0x28a5 0x1) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

How should I change this:

```
-(void)signUp:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.api signup:self.Email.text
                                   password:self.Password.text
                       confirmationPassword:self.ConfirmPassword.text
                                  firstName:self.FirstName.text
                          completionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    } else {
        if ([[response objectForKey:Status] isEqualToString:Success]) {
        self.appDel.theNewUser = [response objectForKey:User];
        self.appDel.theNewUserProfile = [response objectForKey:Profile];
            [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"FAIL: %@", response);
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SignUp Failed"
                                        message:[response description]
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }
}];

}
```

Comment: Please tell us the crash message that you are receiving.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x15d2012 0x12dfe7e 0x1598a95 0x15c54e9 0xe116 0x7955 0x12f3705 0x22a920 0x22a8b8 0x2eb671 0x2ebbcf 0x2ead38 0x25a33f 0x25a552 0x2383aa 0x229cf8 0x2634df9 0x2634ad0 0x1547bf5 0x1547962 0x1578bb6 0x1577f44 0x1577e1b 0x26337e3 0x2633668 0x22765c 0x297d 0x28a5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Also do you think defining the new keys(theNewUser , theNewUserProfile) is also required or I could have used currentUser and currentUserProfile that i had for login?

Comment: Ok cool.  Easy fix (see answer below).

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception. I'm not sure whether its happening in the above posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sign up method (or better yet, in your API class), detect nil and empty values.  The issue right now is that you're inserting a nil value into a dictionary.

Here's an example using your code.  I check if any of the value lengths are equal to zero and if so, log a little error.

```
-(void)signUp:(UIButton *)sender
{

    if ([[[self Email] text] length] == 0 ||
        [[[self Password] text] length] == 0 ||
        [[[self ConfirmPassword] text] length] == 0 ||
        [[[self FirstName] text] length] == 0) {

        // add an error alert here?

        NSLog(@"Hold on there!  You haven't filled everything in.");

        return;

    }

    [self.api signup:self.Email.text
                                   password:self.Password.text
                       confirmationPassword:self.ConfirmPassword.text
                                  firstName:self.FirstName.text
                          completionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    } else {
        if ([[response objectForKey:Status] isEqualToString:Success]) {
        self.appDel.theNewUser = [response objectForKey:User];
        self.appDel.theNewUserProfile = [response objectForKey:Profile];
            [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"FAIL: %@", response);
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SignUp Failed"
                                        message:[response description]
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }
}];

}
```

Comment: Thanks problem solved, but how did this case handled for Login?  and also how can I show the message to user on the screen?

Comment: Not sure why it isn't crashing in login for you as you haven't posted those methods.  Nil values, like what is protected against above, *is* your issue though.

Comment: for login it recieves the fail message from json as following:   login Failed:  reason= "Wrong user/password"; status = fail;}